# Standard Input - Counting chars/words/lines

Tags: c

I've written some code for finding the # of chars, lines and words in a standard input but I have a few questions.

1. On running the program - It doesn't grab any inputs from me. Am I able to use shell redirection for this?
2. My word count - only counts if `getchar()` is equal to the escape ' or a `' '` space. I want it so that it also counts if its outside of a decimal value range on the ASCII table. IE. if `getchar() !=`  in the range of `a->z` and `A->Z` or a ', `wordcount += 1`.

I was thinking about using a decimal value range here to represent the range - ie: `getchar() != (65->90 || 97->122 || \' ) -> wordcount+1`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII for ref.

Would this be the best way of going about answering this? and if so, what is the best way to implement the method?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned long int charcount;
    unsigned long int wordcount;
    unsigned long int linecount;
    int c = getchar();

    while (c != EOF) {
        //characters
        charcount += 1;

        //words separated by characters outside range of a->z, A->Z and ' characters.
        if  (c == '\'' || c == ' ')
            wordcount += 1; 

        //line separated by \n 
        if (c == '\n')
            linecount += 1;
    }    
    printf("%lu %lu %lu\n", charcount, wordcount, linecount);
}
```

Comment: Please do not use a decimal range to specify alphabet chars. Use `'A'`, `'a'`, `'Z'`, `'z'`, but an alternative is to use `isalpha()` in `ctype.h`.

Comment: "It doesn't grab any inputs from me". Well it does - one character. Because you have only called `getchar` once. Perhaps you meant to call it in the loop.

Comment: @WeatherVane So something like if getchar() == isalpha() ... ?
thanks kaylum I tossed it inside the loop, thanks! :P

Comment: You need to **initialise** your variables.

Comment: @DanielJour I was under the impression just setting them as is would initiliaze them - guess thats not the case. I'll add a =0 to them now

Comment: Yes, that would be good. Otherwise you get undefined behaviour. One more thing: words can probably also be separated by lines.

Comment: @Code_Penguin you can read each char with `while ((c=getchar())!=EOF) {...}` within which you would test with `if(isalpha(c)) {...}`

Comment: @Code_Penguin variables are only initialised to `0` if they are `static` or global. Local (automatic) variables are not initialised.

Comment: @WeatherVane  I've put in isalpha(c)==0 as one of the conditions for wordcount+1 but I'm worried that if the user just types in a single special character that the count will +1 then too. I dont think it should be doing that. =/

Comment: @DanielJour So you mean that within the wordcount+1 conditions that I include c=='\n' as well? What if the user just inputs a new lines as the first entry - I guess that would EOF. Hmm yea that does seem like it would work well, but even then if they type a special character and new line - it will wordcount+1. I need to figure out how to exclude that case from word count +1

Comment: I'd say instead of thinking about what is not a word you should probably just increase your count whenever you actually find a word.

Comment: @Code_Penguin please do not edit your question to keep track with suggestions. The question will look stupid later. (Why is this right???) You are now calling `getchar()` twice in the loop.

Comment: @Code_Penguin: I rolled back your last edit.  You were on the right track except for the `c = getchar()` inside the loop.  Look at the code in my answer, but do not modify your question because it makes the discussion inconsistent.

Comment: You realize that by using `isalpha()` you are abandoning ASCII for the character set/encoding (C locale) that your program is started with. But then maybe you didn't actually mean ASCII anyway.

Comment: @chqrlie Oh I see! I'll make sure not to modify my OG questions from now on :) thanks!

Comment: @TomBlodget Yea, I did realize that but it came to me that I dont think I need it to be strictly ascii considered so you're right :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has multiple problems:

- You do not initialize the `charcount`, `wordcount` nor `linecount`.  Uninitialized local variables with automatic storage must be initialized before used, otherwise you invoke undefined behavior.
- You only read a single byte from standard input.  You should keep reading until you get `EOF`.
- Your method for detecting words is incorrect: it is questionable whether `'` is a delimiter, but you seem to want to specifically consider it to be.  The standard `wc` utility considers only white space to separate words.  Furthermore, multiple separators should only count for 1.

Here is a corrected version with your semantics, namely words are composed of letters, everything else counting as separators:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned long int charcount = 0;
    unsigned long int wordcount = 0;
    unsigned long int linecount = 0;
    int c, lastc = '\n';
    int inseparator = 1;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        charcount += 1;  // characters
        if (isalpha(c)) {
            wordcount += inseparator;
            inseparator = 0;
        } else {
            inseparator = 1;
            if (c == '\n')
                linecount += 1;
        }
        lastc = c;
    }
    if (lastc != '\n')
        linecount += 1;  // count the last line if not terminated with \n

    printf("%lu %lu %lu\n", charcount, wordcount, linecount);
}
```

Comment: This gives 1 less word than it should I believe - wordcount+ should be in the else statement with inseparator =1 in the if statement and 0 post wordcount increment in the else statement.

Comment: @Code_Penguin: `wordcount` is incremented on each boundary from nonword to word, including at the start of the file. Do you have an example where it fails?

Comment: @Code_Penguin: If you move the update on `wordcount` to the `else` branch, you will miss the last word of a file that ends on a letter (not followed by an end of line).

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
while((getchar()) != EOF )
```

As the head of you loop.  As you have it getchar will read one character, the while block will loop around with no further **getchar()** ocurring !